# How to replace deprecated get() Function on CMSObject?

Tags: joomla-5.x, deprecated, joomla-6.x

In PHP Storm I am always tells me that the CMSObject->get() function is deprecated and that I should implement my own getter. I would, if I could... This message comes with standard things like:

```
...
$item = parent::getItem($pk);
$params = json_decode($item->get('params'));
...
```

This call is made within a model, for example. Get the item - Get the params - how should I do it differently? $item is already a "CMSObject" here.

Thanks for your suggestions. It would be nice if a new Extension would also run on J6 then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my getItem (J6) in a single record model example. Hope this helps.

```
    /**
     * Method to get an object.
     * @param   integer $id The id of the object to get.
     * @return  mixed    Object on success, false on failure.
     * @throws Exception
     */

public function getItem($id = null)
{
    if ($this->_item === null) {
        $this->_item = false;

        if (empty($id)) {
            $id = $this->getState('application.id');
        }

        // Get a level row instance.
        $table = $this->getTable();

        // Attempt to load the row.
        if ($table->load($id)) {

            // Check published state.
            if ($published = $this->getState('filter.published')) {
                if (isset($table->state) && $table->state != $published) {
                    throw new \Exception(Text::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_ITEM_NOT_LOADED'), 403);
                }
            }

            // Convert the Table to a clean Object.
            $properties  = $table->getProperties(1);
            $this->_item = ArrayHelper::toObject($properties, 'stdClass');

        }

        if (empty($this->_item)) {
            throw new \Exception(Text::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_ITEM_NOT_LOADED'), 404);
        }
    }

    if (isset($this->_item->created_by)) {
        $this->_item->created_by_name = MycomponentHelper::getSpecificUser($this->_item->created_by)->name;
    }

    if (isset($this->_item->modified_by)) {
        $this->_item->modified_by_name = MycomponentHelper::getSpecificUser($this->_item->modified_by)->name;
    }

    return $this->_item;
}
```

As for params, I get these from the populateState function.

```
// Load the parameters.
$params       = Factory::getApplication('com_mycomponent')->getParams();
$params_array = $params->toArray();
```

Comment: This is site side of website.  So what parameters are you after, component params or menu params and do you need them in the model?

Comment: It's a bit weird to explain - i load the params of a Custom Module Instance so my  Model / Table gets the information from #_modules - Based on your answer, I thought about it again and came up with the following solution:
$item = parent::getItem($pk);
$params = new Registry($item->params);
$sourceMethod = $params->get('source_method', null); ...
In Fact i need the "item" Params that way its working